# Send file in response without downloading it

Tags: java, http, video-streaming

I have tried to build a http server to streaming video using HLS. I have process the response like below.

```
private void handleResponse(HttpExchange exchange, String fileNameValue) {
    OutputStream responseStream = exchange.getResponseBody();

    File file = new File(fileNameValue);
    try {
        String encoding = "UTF-8";
        String response = FileUtils.readFileToString(file, encoding);
        exchange.getResponseHeaders().set("Content-Type", "application/x-mpegURL");
        exchange.getResponseHeaders().set("Accept-Ranges", "bytes");
        exchange.getResponseHeaders().set("Cache-Control", "max-age=0, no-cache, no-store");
        exchange.sendResponseHeaders(200, response.length());
        responseStream.write(response.getBytes());
        responseStream.flush();
        responseStream.close();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

But the browsers always download the file instead of playing it. And VLC Media Player doesn't play it too.

I want to get the result like this.
[image]

Can you show me the way to do it? Some keywords for researching are also appreciated.

Comment: HLS is supported natively only on certain browsers/platforms: https://caniuse.com/http-live-streaming. You could use a JavaScript based player.

Comment: Yeah! I have figured it out by myself that their website using xhr so the file appears in the Network section. So I use hls.js and get the same result :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have figured out that their website using xhr to send request so the file appears in the Network section.

I use hls.js after that and get the same result :)